# Syntax error, unexpected end of file in my laravel code

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 6 to create an insert blade. When I wanted to display the view, it generated an error as shown below:

> error:syntax error, unexpected end of file

With this code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','insert')

@section('content')
    @if(session('message'))
        <div class="">
            {{session('message')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    <br/>
    <form class="" id="feedback_form" method="post" action="{{route('insert')}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />

        <div class="">
            <label for="name" class=" ">Tên sản phẩm<span class=""> :</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class=""/>
        </div>

        <div class=" ">
            <label for="name" class=" ">Mô tả<span class=""> :</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="description" class=""/>
        </div>

        <div class=" ">
            <label for="name" class=" ">Danh mục<span class=""> :</span></label>
            <select name="cate">
                @foreach($cate as $ca)
                <option value="{{ $ca->id }}">{{ $ca->name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <div class="">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">SAVE</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

What's the problem?

Comment: you forgot `@endforeach`

Comment: what is error ? show me image ?

Comment: You open two sections but only seem to end one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just put this code**

you forgot to put `@endforeach`

```
 <select name="cate">
                @foreach($cate as $ca)
                <option value="{{ $ca->id }}">{{ $ca->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you write foreach in a blade file you need to end it by endforeach.same for if in blade file like endif.So here is your error for not endforeach.
Try this,

```
@foreach($cate as $ca)
    <option value="{{ $ca->id }}">{{ $ca->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```